# Use SharpMap with WebGL Earth

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharpmap

I'm trying to display a layer on top of a WebGL Earth view inside an Asp.Net 5, MVC 6 website. I have no problem to do this in a desktop application, but I am totally unable to do it on the website.

I have all the data in a shapefile database, and access it with SharpMap. I create a SharpMap.Map object and provide a web method (GET) to fetch the image.

```
[Route("Zoo")]
public IActionResult Zoo(string service, string version, string request, int x, int y, int z)
{

    if (request == "GetMap")
    {                
        Image image = MapRepository.Map.GetMap();

        return base.File(image.ToStream(ImageFormat.Png), "image/png");
    }
    else
    {
        // return capabilities
    }
}
```

However the image returned does not match the 3D globe on WebGL earth. Initially I wanted to create an WMS compliant service, but I couldn't find any working samples nor tips on how to do this.

Also, SharpMap is not updated for MVC6 and the only sample I could find won't work, since it's using the old HttpContext.

Maybe the whole approach is wrong, and I should be returning the polygons an let WebGL do the render... I'm not sure.

---

Currently I just need to display country borders and fill each country with a given color. If there's a better way than what I'm doing, I'd be happy to know!